# What is the proper way to add 'exclude=160' to <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '')); ?>?

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently learned how to integrate wordpress to my HTML/CSS site. I have a decent grasp on HTML/CSS and some Javascript knowledge. I haven't learned a whole lot about PHP just yet but I have been making it work for this first project.

I'm not sure how to research my problem but I'm having trouble adding 
    'exclude=160' to `<?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '')); ?>`

I'm just not sure of the proper format, everything I have tried either gives me an error or an undesired effect.

I'm willing to learn if someone will point me in the right direction, I couldn't figure out how to search for the answer though. I'm planning on learning PHP from the ground up but for now I would like to finish this first project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '', 'exclude' => '160')); ?>`?

Also, the information you'll want to look up is [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/arrays), the documentation is pretty well written and is one of the most valuable resources you'll need to get acquainted with when learning or working with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. This is the error I got with that code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/header.php on line 43

I'll take a look at that page you linked, thanks!

Comment: <?php wp_list_pages(array(
  
   'title_li' => '',
   'exclude' => '169',)); ?> worked though... strange